# Angular Chart.js does not show trendline

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am using Angular with Chart.js and I need to add a trendline. I have added the `chartjs-plugin-trendline.js` plugin and code as below but it does not show the trendline.

HTML Code:

```
<canvas id="base" class="chart-bar" chart-labels="vm.ts_labels" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="vm.generalSatisfactionLine" chart-dataset-override="vm.overallGraphDataOveride" chart-options="vm.overallGraphOptions">
```

Angular code:

```
vm.overallGraphOptions = {
    elements:
        {
            point:
                {
                    radius: 9,
                    hoverRadius: 7.5
                }
        },

    trendlineLinear: {
        style: "rgba(255,105,180, .8)",
        width: 2
    }
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 5000,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
        }
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: true
            },
            ticks: {
                display: true
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            type: "linear",
            position: "left",
            id: 'satisfaction',
            gridLines: {
                display: true
            },
            ticks: {
                display: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                callback: function (label, index, labels) {
                    return label * 10;
                },
            },
            labels: {
                show: true,
            }
        },
        {
            type: "linear",
            position: "right",
            id: 'responses',
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
            ticks: {
                display: false
            },
            labels: {
                show: true,
            }
        }],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be specifying a line chart:

```
<canvas id="base" class="chart-bar" chart-labels="vm.ts_labels" class="chart chart-line" ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The [readme for chartjs-plugin-trendline](https://github.com/Makanz/chartjs-plugin-trendline#readme) states that only **bar** charts are supported.